# What is "done" callback function in Passport Strategy Configure "use" function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, passport.js

I'm an node.js and express.js noob. This question may seems silly but I'm really in confusion.

I'm trying to configure [Local Strategry](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) authentication by using [passport](http://passportjs.org/). As shown in the official documentation, we can figure this Local Strategy by the following code,

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

My confusion is about the `done` callback function. When the official docs show this local strategy using as a middleware in the route handler, there is no need to pass the function parameter for this `done` callback.

```
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

So, isn't this `done` callback function will be null if we don't provide the function parameter? If not, what is that `done` callback function and what processes will be happening in this `done` callback function?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`done` is a method [called internally by the strategy implementation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L80).

Then it navigates you, as you can see, to one of the `success` / `error` / `fail` methods (again, by the implementation. [there are more options](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/0b3931330e245d8e8851328a7dc436433d6411c9/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L171)).
Each of these options may [calls](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/0b3931330e245d8e8851328a7dc436433d6411c9/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L243) to the `next`, where in your snippet code is the following:

```
function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

When `success` is called, [it can attach the user to the request](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/0b3931330e245d8e8851328a7dc436433d6411c9/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L224) or do other things, depending on your needs (it looks for the `options` you pass to `passport.authenticate`). If you want to determine when `next` will be called, you should use [`custom callback`](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate) which gives you more flexibility.

I strongly recommend that you read the source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After few hours I asked this question, I gradually understand that "done" might be managed internally by passport. Now I clear when I see your answer.

Comment: passportjs documentation needs major improvement

Comment: If someone has the time and experience, please heavily consider making high-quality passportjs docs...

Answer (score 7):

It's now 2022 and I had the same question.  The passport documentation has improved and it describes the `done` method (also called `cb`) here: https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/strategies/#verify-function.  You will need to call this yourself in your strategy's verify function.

> A verify function yields under one of three conditions: success, failure, or an error.
>
> If the verify function finds a user to which the credential belongs, and that credential is valid, it calls the callback with the authenticating user:
>
> ```
> return cb(null, user);
> ```
>
> If the credential does not belong to a known user, or is not valid, the verify function calls the callback with false to indicate an authentication failure:
>
> ```
> return cb(null, false);
> ```
>
> If an error occurs, such as the database not being available, the callback is called with an error, in idiomatic Node.js style:
>
> ```
> return cb(err);
> ```