# What does done returns in passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

In passport JS examples, there are lines like `return done(arguments here)`
What does `done` returns, and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "done" callback function in Passport Strategy Configure "use" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153865/what-is-done-callback-function-in-passport-strategy-configure-use-function)

Comment: It doesn't answer what does done returns

Comment: Done returns either 1. nothing ('undefined') or 2. a simple error object.